# Bootstrap activetab redirecting to first tab

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I used `bootstrap activetab` as an anchor link  say

```
/about-us/contacts?activetab=1
```

I have 3 tabs in this [page](http://www.wshed33.devsoho.com/about-us/contacts?activetab=1) according to my anchor link `activetab=1` it should redirect to second tab but whether it is `1` or `2` it is being redirected to `0` tab always.

Comment: i cant find error on there. Can you describe more??

Comment: I checked your page, but i didnt see anything wrong. It worked fine for me.

Comment: I am sorry where I am unclear?? @Abdulla

Comment: @Dorvalla is it being redirected to Recycling/HHW Disposal tab ??

Comment: all works fine @dh47.

Comment: Yes, i see what you mean, now. I tried it in the link bar and indeed it shows the first tab, despite what active tab i pick. However, you dont check for active tab, since its not the right search item. Your a href in has a data link to `#txmod_113-1` instead of `#activetab` which you call in your link.

Comment: But for me it is showing first tab the actual order was `0,1 and 2` right?? In that case I need to have `Recycling` tab active on page load but it is `watershed tab`

Comment: `watershed` is the first loaded item for me. I dont know what your logical idea of loading is, that is something for you to decide.

Comment: I want to load `Recycling` first in this [way](http://www.wshed25.devsoho.com/about-us/contacts?activetab=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by writing some Javascript to achieve this the code goes in this way...

I fetched the current `URL` and them split it into get my required URL part i.e `activetab=1/activetab=2` then I wrote condition and done by adding class and removing class for the required tabs.

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var url = window.location.href;

            url = url.split("?");
            var activeurl = url[1];
            //alert(url);
            if(activeurl == "activetab=1") {

                jQuery( "#txmod_113 li.first" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113-0" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113 li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113-1" ).addClass( "active" );
                } 
            else if(activeurl == "activetab=2") {

                jQuery( "#txmod_113 li.first" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113-0" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113 li:nth-child(2)" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113-1" ).removeClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113 li.last" ).addClass( "active" );
                jQuery( "#txmod_113-2" ).addClass( "active" );
                }
        });
</script>
```